# Print real roots only in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have something like this:

```
coefs = [28, -36, 50, -22]
print(numpy.roots(coefs))
```

Of course the result is:

```
[ 0.35770550+1.11792657j  0.35770550-1.11792657j  0.57030329+0.j ]
```

However, by using this method, how do I get it only to print the real roots if any (as floats)? Meaning just this for my example:

```
0.57030329
```

Comment: I don't really need it since it has an imaginary part, out of all the equations my script will run, at least one root will be real, and that's the one I need :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it, using [iscomplex](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.iscomplex.html) as follows:

```
r = numpy.roots(coefs)

In [15]: r[~numpy.iscomplex(r)]
Out[15]: array([ 0.57030329+0.j])
```

Also you can use [isreal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isreal.html) as pointed out in comments:

```
In [17]: r[numpy.isreal(r)]
Out[17]: array([ 0.57030329+0.j])
```

Comment: any reason to use the negation of iscomplex instead of isreal?

Comment: @M4rtini Just my happit. But off course, isreal would be more readable:-)

Comment: Probably slightly faster not having to invert the boolean matrix also :)

Comment: @M4rtini Yep. I added is real to the answer.

Answer (score 32):

Do NOT use `.iscomplex()` or `.isreal()`, because `roots()` is a numerical algorithm, and it returns the numerical approximation of the actual roots of the polynomial. This can lead to spurious imaginary parts, that are interpreted by the above methods as solutions.

Example:

```
# create a polynomial with these real-valued roots:
p = numpy.poly([2,3,4,5,56,6,5,4,2,3,8,0,10])
# calculate the roots from the polynomial:
r = numpy.roots(p)
print(r) # real-valued roots, with spurious imaginary part
array([ 56.00000000 +0.00000000e+00j,  10.00000000 +0.00000000e+00j,
         8.00000000 +0.00000000e+00j,   6.00000000 +0.00000000e+00j,
         5.00009796 +0.00000000e+00j,   4.99990203 +0.00000000e+00j,
         4.00008066 +0.00000000e+00j,   3.99991935 +0.00000000e+00j,
         3.00000598 +0.00000000e+00j,   2.99999403 +0.00000000e+00j,
         2.00000000 +3.77612207e-06j,   2.00000000 -3.77612207e-06j,
         0.00000000 +0.00000000e+00j])
# using isreal() fails: many correct solutions are discarded
print(r[numpy.isreal(r)])
[ 56.00000000+0.j  10.00000000+0.j   8.00000000+0.j   6.00000000+0.j
   5.00009796+0.j   4.99990203+0.j   4.00008066+0.j   3.99991935+0.j
   3.00000598+0.j   2.99999403+0.j   0.00000000+0.j]
```

Use some threshold depending on your problem at hand instead. Moreover, since you're interested in the real roots, keep only the real part:

```
real_valued = r.real[abs(r.imag)<1e-5] # where I chose 1-e5 as a threshold
print(real_valued)
```

Comment: +1 - A lot of people forget that numerical imprecision can lead to insignificant imaginary coefficients and no matter how small they are, numbers would still be classified as imaginary.

Comment: This only solves the spurious imaginary part problem sometimes.  It is possible that there are actual imaginary roots with a small imaginary part.

Comment: Why do you post such an explicit example of the WRONG solution but don't show the usage of the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help.

```
 roots = np.roots(coeff);
 for i in range(len(roots)):
     if np.isreal(roots[i]):
         print(np.real(roots[i]))
```