# Numpy throws incorrect roots

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using Numpy to solve quadratic equations, but I found that for a certain equation I'm not getting the correct result using the function `numpy.roots()`

The following equation:

[image]

Has these roots (tested manually and with online calculators):

[image]

But entering the command `numpy.roots([1, 6, 9])` the output that I got was

```
array([-3. +3.72529030e-08j, -3. -3.72529030e-08j])
```

I tried with different equations, but in those cases the Numpy's result was correct. The problem is with this particular example. The other successful examples that I tried were:

```
numpy.roots([1, 6, 13])

numpy.roots([1, -6, 17])

numpy.roots([1, -5, 6])

numpy.roots([1, -10, 25])

numpy.roots([1, 4, 4])
```

Is there any possibility of being a bug or I'm misundersanding the behavior of the function?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like just a precision/rounding issue to me - the answer is oh-so-close to -3, and x**2 + 6*x + 9 is -1.7763568394002505e-15+0j which is 0 for all practical intents.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084225/4909087

Comment: Floating point math is inherently inexact. The complex part is essentially zero.

Comment: Excellent, I've seen that question, but I didn't think that the inaccuracy of the algorithm would also make a difference in case of a simple quadratic equation. Thanks for the quick answers!